# Need help cleaning up a log file with bash

Tags: bash

```
06/25 11:07:24 [INFO] *** CONTROL OUT bytes: 020106/25 11:07:24 [INFO]*** CONTROL IN bytes:080205063D715EB8F4740400200000FFE7010002000000000000000000000006/25 11:07:24 [INFO] hardware revision: 006/25 11:07:24 [INFO] dongle firmware version: 2.506/25 11:07:24 [INFO] dongle bluetooth address: 06:3D:71:5E:B8:F406/25 11:07:24 [INFO] CLIENT: [06/25 11:07:24] Dongle | Version|"majorVersion":2,"minorVersion":5,"deviceAddr":6,61,113,94,184,244],"flashEraseTime":1140,"firmwareStartAddress":8192,"firmwareEndAddress":124927,"ccIC":2,"hardwareRevision":0,"revision":0}06/25 11:07:24 [INFO] CLIENT: [06/25 11:07:24] Dongle | Set Power Level | 506/25 11:07:24 [INFO] Received message from client.06/25 11:07:24 [INFO] *** CONTROL OUT bytes: 020D050
```

So I want to clean this up by putting each command/section on a new line, like this,

```
06/25 11:07:24 [INFO] CLIENT: [06/25 11:07:24] Dongle | Set Power Level | 5
06/25 11:07:24 [INFO] Received message from client.
06/25 11:07:24 [INFO] *** CONTROL OUT bytes: 020D050
```

but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Do the lines really butt up against one another like that? The end of one "line" is directly before the start of the timestamp on the next "line"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*UPDATE: Comments merged in the answer! Thanks, [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) and [pabouk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320437/pabouk).*</sup>

Assuming your string is in `filename`:

```
# bound to GNU sed, because of '-r/--regexp-extended'
sed -r 's:[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}:\n&:g' <filename

# without '-r':
sed 's:[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]:\n&:g' <filename
```

For better safety, [pabouk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320437/pabouk) suggests matching a longer pattern:

```
sed -r 's@[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}@\n&@g' <filename
```

Comment: `sed ... <filename` (or its also-POSIX-legal synonym `<filename sed ...`) is significantly faster than `cat filename | sed ...` -- having one process read from a file and write to a pipeline, and a second process read from that pipeline is much less efficient than having the second process read straight from the file!

Comment: If you use the whole matched string in the output, you do not need to use the sub-expression. Also there is no need to escape `/` when you do not use it as a delimiter. Do just this: `s:[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}:\n&:g`. --- Additionally to be safer I would match also the time: `s@[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}@\n&@g` --- It is worth mentioning that the `-r` option (extended regex) is an extension of GNU sed.

Comment: @pabouk: thank you. the answer has been updated to include your notes.

Comment: You are welcome :) One more suggestion :) You can extend the sed program by two commands (separated by `;`): ``s@^\n@@;a\``. The first one removes the newline prepended to the file by the first substitution. The second one adds a newline to the end if missing. With GNU sed this works even if the input has some newlines.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"; } { print rt $0; rt = RT; }' < filename
```

Comment: This script does not pass the date to the output.